# Using php inside python code ,google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a project that already written in php, and now i am using python in google app engine, actually i want to use the api that google support for python, for example : datastore, blobstore ... and also to save my time to re write the code again in python !

so, is it possible to run php script in python code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/) to write different parts of the same application in different languages, or the same language but with different scaling and uptime characteristics.

Using this you could combine parts of PHP and parts of Python in the same application, and use HTTP calls or tasks queues to make calls between the two parts.

Comment: True enough. You can have different runtimes in the same application umbrella, but you can't run PHP inside python as the question stated. Perhaps that's not what OP was asking.

Comment: i'd argue that calling a php script in the same application from the python code is running PHP inside python ;)

Answer (score 2):

Those runtimes (Py, PHP, Java. etc.) are isolated from each other and are tightly sandboxed. So when you deploy a Python app, for example, it doesn't have access to the PHP or Java runtime. So, it's not possible to run PHP inside a python sandbox, at least not in the appengine platform.